# Inserting multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have WindowTable with following data :

```
SELECT  Id FROM WindowTable WHERE OwnerRef=12

 Id
----
25000
25001
25003
25004
25005
25006
25007
25008
```

I want to Insert 3 row per each WindowTable Row in ActionTable
Like this :

```
Id    WindowsRef     ActionName     ActionName2     

-----------------------------------------------
1       25000          'Add'          'E'
2       25000          'DELETE'       'H'
3       25000          'UPDATE'       'B'  
4       25001          'ADD'          'E'
5       25001          'DELETE'       'H' 
6       25001          'Update'       'B'
.         .              .
.         .              .
```

**ActionTable.Id is not identity column**

Comment: u need add 3 queries like this: `insert into ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) select Id,"ADD" FROM WindowTable WHERE OwnerRef=12`,`insert into ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) select Id,"UPDATE" FROM WindowTable WHERE OwnerRef=12`,`insert into ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) select Id,"DELETE" FROM WindowTable WHERE OwnerRef=12`

Comment: Is this a one off population of `ActionTable`? Or something that will be repeated?

Comment: What is the reason that `ActionTable.Id` is not an identity column? (This may affect the approach to generating values.)

Comment: Because I working With Existing Databases

Comment: What is the rule for determining whether to set `ActionName` to "Add" or "ADD"? "Update" or "UPDATE"? Is it always "DELETE", or sometimes "delete" or "Delete"?

Comment: add del and update per each windowsRef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or:

```
insert into ActionTable (Id, WindowsRe, ActionName, ActionName2)
select
   isnull((select max(at.Id) from ActionTable at), 0) +
   row_number() over (order by w.Id, a.Action),
   w.Id, a.Action, a.Action2
from WindowsTable w
cross join
(
  select 'Add' as Action, 'E' as Action2
  union all select 'Delete', 'H'
  union all select 'Update', 'B'
) a
```

**UPD**: Fixed misstyping. Thanks @Hua_Trung for comment

**UPD2**: Added `ActionTable.Id` generation

**UPD3**: Added `ActionName2`

Comment: nice answer ! nearly forget it ! but `a.Action` or `a.ActionName` ??

Comment: Thanks  again, but how to Add ActionName2 Column?

Comment: Edited one more time

Comment: Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'uniqueiActions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'info.ActionTable'. The duplicate key value is (17, Add).

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
insert into ActionTable(WindowsRef, ActionName)
select id WindowsRef, 'Add'
  from WindowsTable
union all
select id WindowsRef, 'DELETE'
  from WindowsTable
union all
select id WindowsRef, 'UPDATE'
  from WindowsTable
```

(Assuming `ActionTable.Id` is an identity column or otherwise database generated.)

To generate `id` values as well

```
insert into ActionTable(id, WindowsRef, ActionName)
select
    (isnull(select max(id) from ActionTable, 0)
        + row_number() over (order by x.WindowsRef, x.ActionName)
    ) id,
    x.WindowsRef, x.ActionName
from (
    select id WindowsRef, 'Add' ActionName
      from WindowsTable
    union all
    select id WindowsRef, 'DELETE' ActionName
      from WindowsTable
    union all
    select id WindowsRef, 'UPDATE' ActionName
      from WindowsTable
) x
```

Answer (score 3):

one more approach using apply.Using sample data from Praveen ND

```
select *,row_number() over (order by id) as id from @WindowTable
cross apply
(
values('add','E'),
      ('delete','h'),
      ('update','b')
)b(action,action2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you to create the script for inserting to ActionTable

```
DECLARE @WindowTable TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @WindowTable VALUES
(25001),
(25003),
(25004),
(25005),
(25006),
(25007),
(25008)

SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) VALUES ('+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',ADD)' FROM @WindowTable
UNION
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) VALUES ('+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',UPDATE)' FROM @WindowTable
UNION
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (WindowsRe,ActionName) VALUES ('+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',DELETE)' FROM @WindowTable
```

Note : Considering ID in ActionTable as IDENTITY.

IF ID in ActionTable is not an IDENTITY : 
Try to make use of below Query :

```
DECLARE @WindowTable TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @WindowTable VALUES
(25001),
(25003),
(25004),
(25005),
(25006),
(25007),
(25008)

DECLARE @id INT =1;
DECLARE @id1 INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @WindowTable)
DECLARE @id2 INT = (SELECT 2 *COUNT(*) FROM @WindowTable)


SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (ID,WindowsRe,ActionName,ActionName2) VALUES ('+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @id) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+','+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',ADD,''E'')' FROM @WindowTable
UNION
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (ID,WindowsRe,ActionName,ActionName2) VALUES ('+CAST(@id1+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @id1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+','+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',UPDATE,''B'')' FROM @WindowTable
UNION
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ActionTable (ID,WindowsRe,ActionName,ActionName2) VALUES ('+CAST(@id2+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @id2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+','+ CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+',DELETE,''H'')' FROM @WindowTable
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but ActionTable.Id is not identity column

Comment: I had added, a new query. try to make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

### Test Data

```
;WITH cte_TestData(WindowsRef) AS
(
SELECT 25000 UNION ALL
SELECT 25001 UNION ALL
SELECT 25003 UNION ALL
SELECT 25004 UNION ALL
SELECT 25005 UNION ALL
SELECT 25006 UNION ALL
SELECT 25007 UNION ALL
SELECT 25008
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
    a.WindowsRef,
    b.ActionName,
    b.ActionName2
FROM cte_TestData a
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'Add' AS ActionName,'E' AS ActionName2   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DELETE','H' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'UPDATE','B') b
ORDER BY a.WindowsRef
```

## Against Actual Data

```
;WITH cte_TestData(WindowsRef) AS
(
SELECT  Id
FROM WindowTable 
WHERE OwnerRef=12
)
,cte_Action AS
(
SELECT 'Add' AS ActionName,'E' AS ActionName2   UNION ALL
SELECT 'DELETE','H' UNION ALL
SELECT 'UPDATE','B'
)
--INSERT INTO <DestinationTable> 
/* 
- Replace <DestinationTable> with Target Table Name 
- If the destination table has data the the ID has to be incremented accordingly. 
-- In that case define a variable, get MAX of that ID and add that to the below 
   auto generated ID to preserve the sequence. 
--Better yet, use Identity column as your ID Column
*/
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
    a.WindowsRef,
    b.ActionName,
    b.ActionName2
FROM cte_TestData a
CROSS JOIN cte_Action b
--WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM <DestinationTable> c WHERE c.WindowsRef = a.WindowsRef) 
/* 
Enable to ensure duplicate records are not inserted, Replace <DestinationTable> with Target Table Name 
*/
ORDER BY a.WindowsRef
```